# When I click on DOM elements of a page, I get the following Firebug popup showing:

Tags: firefox, firebug

**Version Details.**

Firefox Browser = 53.0.2 (32-bit)

FireBug = 2.0.19

[image]

It's really annoying. How do I disable that?

Comment: try to remove unwanted extension

Comment: Vipul, I had already done this. but still facing the same issue..!!

Comment: Note that the [development of Firebug is discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) and it stops working once [multiprocess Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) is enabled, but at latest in [Firefox 57, which only supports WebExtensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/). Firebug users are advised to use the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.

Comment: lol @VipulUpadhyay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This popup is called *Quick Info Box* and can be disabled by unchecking the [*HTML* panel option *Show Quick Info Box*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu):

[image: *Show Quick Info Box* *HTML* panel option]